# Getting rid of popup ads

Tags: gmail, malware

when I open gmail, this super annoying popup opens.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: What does the pop-up look like? A pop-up ad on GMail sounds like malware or injected page content by your ISP or a rogue web proxy.

Comment: Actually, I've realized now it doesn't come from gmail itself, the popup happens after I click on the gmail icon, and then get a prompt to enter my login id, but *BEFORE* I enter my id.    Following sam's suggestion I'm hoping to block it with adblock, but it didn't initially work.    I added a custom filter to addblock, that *should* fix it.

Comment: How do you access the login page? Do you go directly to the [encrypted version](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/)? If yes, does Google Chrome complain about mismatching server certificates (Google Chrome pins the official certificates in case your hostel/employer/ISP/government has a valid man-in-the-middle certificate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, playing around with this, I discovered that the problem had nothing to do with gmail at all. I'd set facebook as an additional tab to open on startup. It was the facebook link that was being hijacked. When I removed the facebook url from my set of startup page I was able to open without problems. Ugh, this hijack was extremely aggressive also, and not deterred by adblock. Each time I listed the hijacking url, another one would take it's place. Felt like I was in Windows Land. Hopefully deleting the facebook tab will fix things! Thanks for your help... –  L

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [adblock plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US) or similar browser plugins. I have never had a gmail popup in any browser since installing it.